# Problems adding Nuget (EntityFrameworkCore) to my Xamarin Forms (IOS) Application

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, nuget, entity-framework-core

I am creating a Xamarin Forms application for IOS and I want to store my data in an azure database (if possible). My problem is that I can't add a nuget reference to my project: I am getting this error message:

> An error occurred while retrieving package metadata for 'System.Globalization.4.0.11' from source 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\NuGetFallbackFolder'.
>   '.', hexadecimal value 0x00, is an invalid character. Line 1, position 1.

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHLEg.png)

Would be nice if anybody could help me with this.

Comment: I'd try deleting NuGetFallbackFolder first

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

->delete the packages folder(NuGetFallbackFolder)

-> get nuget command line

-> run commands listed follow and then restore nuget packages

```
nuget.exe locals -clear global-packages
nuget.exe locals -clear packages-cache
nuget.exe locals -clear http-cache
```

If other reference problems can refer to this [doc](https://blog.xamarin.com/xamarin-studio-and-nuget/) , and  store my data in an azure database can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/cosmosdb/).